# Pip with virtualenv not upgrading Django

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip, distribute

I'm using pip with `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute`  and am trying to upgrade Django. `pip install -U Django` should upgrade it according to the docs I found. However, it simply finds the current Django installation and stops.

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the version I want to upgrade to. Currently, I'm stuck with modifying the requirements file, then blowing over the old virtualenv and starting a new one. However, I'd be happy just getting `pip install -U` to upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your `build/` directory in your virtualenv path. Delete the `Django/` dir there and try to run `pip install --upgrade django` again.